# console log the state after using useState doesn't return the current value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

using `console.log()` after using reactjs `useState()` hook, doesn't return the current value of this state, How can I handle this?

Here's code for the case, try to figure out what's the console log display.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function Weather() {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState();

  return (
    <input
      value={weather}
      onChange={(e) => {
        setWeather(e.target.value);
        console.log(weather);
      }}
    />
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Weather />, rootElement);
```

Comment: yes, cause the component is not updated yet. you should use the log in `useEffect`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`useState` by default simply does one thing and one thing only, set the new state and cause a re-render of the function. It is asynchronous in nature so by default, methods running after it usually run.

From your example, on a fresh load of the page, typing 's' causes useState to change the state, but because it is asynchronous, `console.log` will be called with the old state value, i.e. `undefined` (since you didn't set a value. You should consider setting an initial state, if you want to)

```
const [weather, setWeather] = useState('');    // Set the intial state
```

The only way to truly read the value of the state is to use `useEffect`, which is called when there is a re-render of the component. Your method simply becomes:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function Weather() {
    const [weather, setWeather] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => console.log(weather), [weather]);

    const changeValue = event => setWeather(event.target.value);

    return <input value={weather} onChange={changeValue} />;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<Weather />, rootElement);
```

Comment: you said "one thing and one thing only, set the new state and cause a re-render of the function." That is two things not one. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: i have tried this exact thing with my app using <InputText> is there a reason it would be returning undefined?

Answer (score 4):

When you call `setWeather`, you trigger a rerender of your component, which will call again this function. However, the `console.log(weather);`  inside the function still references the first value returned by `useState`, which is your orignal value. If you want to print it you should be doing :

```
console.log(e.target.value);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
onChange={(e) => {
    setWeather(e.target.value);
    console.log(weather);
  }}
```

when this function is fired, since `setWeather` is async, it will be passed to web api. Javascript engine does not handle this function. wep api handles this and when it is done event loop which is part of the web api pass this to the call stack.

call stack is where functions get executed. once async functions are passed to the web api, regardless of its executing time (even though it has 0 second time out), they will not moved to call stack unless javascript engine finishes the execution of sync code. once call stack is free, event loop will pass the function to call stack to be executed.

So in your code, `onChange()` is passed to call stack. Inside of this function, 2 functions have to be executed. since `setWeather` is async, it goes to web api, gets the `e.target.value`, meanwhile console.log gets executed. when there is no sync code left in the call stack, event loop  pushes the setWeather to the call stack to be executed.

Let's say you enter "name" to the input field. after "nam", state is "nam", but when you type "e", this will be executed in webapi, so while it is in web api, console.log will log the current state which is "nam". that is why you will always see the console one character behind

Comment: I liked your explanation but you should have provided a solution as well (I guess) ;)