# Setting state using useState results in empty array on first call

Tags: reactjs, state, use-state, google-map-react

I'm using the `google-map-react` component and I'm attempting to set the coordinates of the position the user clicked on. I have the coordinates, however the first time I click on the map (and the click event is fired), the array `coordinates` returns an empty array.

This is resulting in weird behaviour, where each click returns the coordinates of the previous click? Can anyone see whats going on here?

```
const Map = ({ center, zoom}) => {

    const [ coordinates, setCoordinates ] = useState([]);

    const onMapClick = ({ lat, lng }) => {
        setCoordinates([lat, lng]);
        console.log(coordinates)
    };

    return (
        <div className="map">
            <GoogleMapReact 
                bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'redacted' }}
                defaultCenter={center}
                defaultZoom={zoom}
                onClick={onMapClick}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

Map.defaultProps = {
    center: {
        lat: 53.3439,
        lng: 33.0622
    },
    zoom: 5
}
```

The behaviour is logging the following

```
[]
(2) [51.13790387040561, -11.71807343750003]
(2) [47.709656855536565, 2.1686453124999705]
```

The second log, should be in position 1, and the third log should be in position 2.

Comment: Duplicate of [console log the state after using useState doesn't return the current value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867616/console-log-the-state-after-using-usestate-doesnt-return-the-current-value)

Answer (score 1):

There is an async behavior on useState. Your console.log() will show the old one. Because the state is not updated yet. But if you put your console.log() in useEffect like

```
useEffect(() => {
 console.log(coordinates)
}, [coordinates])
```

You will see it's showing properly after the onClick event.

Your code is working normally. You can put your coordinates state where you want to use them.

Comment: Please avoid answering questions that have already been answered.