# Updating React state after calling document.onpaste?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to setup a functional component that allows the user to copy/paste their clipboard image into the app. In useEffect, I setup document.onpaste . This was working and I was able to get the image and upload it. But I need to have it update the state after paste, so that I can allow them to paste multiple images and keep them in array in state.

I've simplified the problem below. Basically when I paste I want to have it update the counter value, but it doesn't. Counter always = 0. If I use normal react button onclick event, it works fine. I'm guessing the onpaste event is outside of React, but then,

How can I process the paste event and also update the functional state?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const AddAttachmentsContainer = ({ zoneid, tableid, field }) => {
  const [counter,setCounter]=useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.onpaste=(e)=>{GetImage(e);e.preventDefault()}
  },[])

  const GetImage = (e) => {
    setCounter(counter+1)
    console.log(counter)
  }
 }
```

Comment: If my answer helped solve your issue, you can accept it for this post. Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, I'll bet that the state is updated. useState will update the state and trigger a re-render. Since it is asynchronous, console.log will be called with the old state value.

`useEffect(() => console.log(counter), [counter]);`

... don't forget to add `counter` in the second argument of `useEffect`. [see here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)...

Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867616/console-log-the-state-after-using-usestate-doesnt-return-the-current-value)

Alternatively, of course, you can also use [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), but be aware of the use cases for them. It is easy to allow refs to unnecessarily spread through your code.

To be honest, it might be wise to just `setCounter` in the `useEffect` you already have and call your `GetImage` function afterwards... from there, you can retrieve counter. There are multiple approaches to this.

Comment: It's not updated, I click 4 or 5 times, it always shows 0 .

Comment: I found this article which talks about similar issue: The solution they outline didn't work for me though. https://medium.com/geographit/accessing-react-state-in-event-listeners-with-usestate-and-useref-hooks-8cceee73c559

Comment: Refs can be a solution to this problem. Are you getting the same results when using  `useRef`? I have updated more of my answer btw if it helps.

Comment: Actually, the solution in that article did work! Just needed to reference the MyStateRef.current to see updated value.  all good

Comment: Yep! I remember about `ref.current`. Good spot.

Comment: Added section about refs to my answer and relevant links! Hope this helps.