# React setState not pushing value FIRST TIME ONLY

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Noob question on the way... :(

Working with multiple checkbox and setting state is never getting first value event though value is there.

**Console**

[image]

As show above "value" is being printed on selection.

**code**

```
function onChange (e: any) {
        const isChecked = e.target.checked
        const value = e.target.value
        console.log('bool', isChecked, value)
        if(isChecked) {
            console.log('inside val', value)
            setChosenSpeciality([...chosenSpeciality, value])

            console.log('added array', chosenSpeciality)
            filterBySpecialty(chosenSpeciality)
        } else {
            setChosenSpeciality(chosenSpeciality.filter(item => item !== value))
            filterBySpecialty(chosenSpeciality)

            console.log('rest from remove', chosenSpeciality)
        }
    }

<CheckboxContainer>
            {
                   specialties.map((specialty, index) => (
                    <label>  
                        <Checkbox  
                            type="checkbox"
                            name={specialty}
                            value={specialty} 
                            key={index}
                            onClick={onChange}
                        />  
                        {specialty}
                    </label>
                   ))
            }
            </CheckboxContainer>
```

Thanks for any help, have a good one!

Comment: Is your issue that you are expecting `chosenSpeciality` to include the new value here:  `console.log('added array', chosenSpeciality)`

Comment: Setting the state is an asynchronous thing. It queues the state update. If you're expecting it to immediately update before a re-render, that wouldn't be correct. I'm not real sure what you're asking though.

Comment: `setState` (assuming your using `useState` hook) is async, so there's a change that the new state is correclty set but not yet at the time you call `console.log`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867616/console-log-the-state-after-using-usestate-doesnt-return-the-current-value)

Comment: Hi everyone, The page with cheboxes is render and I want to select an item but the first selection don't update the state(showed above). If I click again it happens.

Comment: @SamuelGoldenbaum exactly it never includes the value the first time. In case I click again it is being added. cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue seems like you are expecting the state to updated immediately which is not the case–it is actually an **async** operation.

> This form of setState() is also asynchronous, and multiple calls
> during the same cycle may be batched together.

[Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Update to take this into consideration:

```
function onChange (e: any) {
        const isChecked = e.target.checked
        const value = e.target.value
        console.log('bool', isChecked, value)
        if(isChecked) {
            console.log('inside val', value)
            const temp = [...chosenSpeciality, value];
            setChosenSpeciality(temp)

            console.log('added array', temp)
            filterBySpecialty(temp)
        } else {
            const temp = chosenSpeciality.filter(item => item !== value);
            setChosenSpeciality(temp)
            filterBySpecialty(temp)

            console.log('rest from remove', temp)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Saved the day, cheers!!!