# My firebase realtime push key is changed when I save it in array in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am saving order data in firebase realtime but the push key that I save in array object is different from what I get as push key

```
function confirmOrder() {
  let array = []
  const Oid = firebase.app().database(DATABASE_URL).ref('/Order/').push();

  array.push({
    total: getTotal(),
    oid: Oid.key,
    totalItems: cartItems.length
  })

  for (let index = 0; index < cartItems.length; index++) {
    var key = `item${index + 1}`;
    var obj = {};
    obj[key] = cartItems[index].qty + ' ' + cartItems[index].name + ' Rs.' + cartItems[index].price;
    array.push(obj)
  }

  setOrder(Object.assign(...array))
  firebase.app().database(DATABASE_URL).ref('/Order/' + Oid.key).set(order);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you try `.set({ ...array })` instead of `.set(order)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it's the cause of the issue, but can you try this (shorter) version of the last line?

```
Oid.set(order);
```

---

**Update**: the `setState` method and `useState` hooks asynchronously update the state, so `order` won't yet be updated on the next line.

You can either wait for the order to complete, or simply use `array` as the value:

```
Oid.set(Object.assign(...array));
```

Also see:

- [Is useState synchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119678/is-usestate-synchronous)
- [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)
- [console log the state after using useState doesn't return the current value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867616/console-log-the-state-after-using-usestate-doesnt-return-the-current-value/54867900#54867900)

Comment: Already tried it but didn't worked

Comment: There's another problem, so I updated my answer for that too.